# Invalid multibyte character (US-ASCII) error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, ruby-test

I am writing a test using ruby where I am verifying some data as per below code.

```
array['myLabel'].should eq '(100–200) mg/dL'
```

When I run the test, I am getting an error on this line.

Error is: `invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)` and then below that `syntax error, unexpected $end, expecting keyword_end`

I checked the test and made sure that I have proper end statements everywhere. But I am still getting these errors when I execute the test.

I am noob in ruby. Please suggest if I am missing something.

Comment: is your file saved using a unicode encoding? utf-8 for example.

Answer (score 5):

You need to add `#encoding: UTF-8` at the top of your file that has multi-byte characters in it, as per this topic: [How does the magic comment ( # Encoding: utf-8 ) in ruby​​ work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879237/how-does-the-magic-comment-encoding-utf-8-in-ruby-works)

Comment: And the reason why this is necessary is because the dash isn't an ordinary hyphen but an en dash.