# How do I put a pound sign in the subject of an email with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

The following does not work

```
subject = "The amount of &#163;#{@amount} has been sent to your account".html_safe
mail(:to => @email, :subject => subject, :reply_to => 'support@xyz.com')
```

Neither does

```
subject = "The amount of &pound;#{@amount} has been sent to your account".html_safe
```

How can I show the pound sign in the email subject?

Comment: Did you try this yet? `subject = "The amount of ##{@amount} has been sent to your account"` (without `.html_safe`)

Comment: @pdobb: A Hash sign (#) is something completely different from the pound sign (£)...

Comment: @pdobb yea but using a hash doesnt get me my pound sign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Email subjects (as all headers in an email) do not accept HTML entities as used on a web page. Instead, they use several different encodings on non-ASCII data, all of which should be automatically applied by the `mail` gem.

As such, it it probably the easiest to just put the character directly into the subject variable without any additional encoding applied by yourself:

```
subject = "The amount of £#{@amount} has been sent to your account"
mail(:to => @email, :subject => subject, :reply_to => 'support@xyz.com')
```

Note that unless you use Ruby 2.0 (which defaults to utf-8 source encoding iirc), you probably have to put a [magic encoding comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8879237/how-does-the-magic-comment-encoding-utf-8-in-ruby-works) on top of your source file in order for ruby to interpret your source code as UTF-8 similar to this

```
# encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: thanks but I get the following error with this approach SyntaxError: /Path/to/mailer.rb:29: invalid multibyte char (US-ASCII)