# How can I use encode utf-8 in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding

I am trying to extract a word from a first line of file:

`LOCATION,Feij�,AC,a,b,c`

this way:

`2.0.0-p247 :005 > File.foreach(file).first`

> => "LOCATION,Feij\xF3,AC,a,b,c\r\n"`

but when I try to use split:

`2.0.0-p247 :008 > File.foreach(file).first.split(",")`

> ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8     from (irb):8:in `split'
>     from (irb):8    from
>   /home/bleh/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/irb:13:in`'

What I expected is: Feijó

I already try a lot of combinations like .encode and .force_encoding.

Some ideas?

Comment: Can you try `File.foreach(file, :encoding => 'utf-8').first` ?

Comment: Hi Arup. Yeah, I received Feij\xF3. When try to split, same error

Comment: Okay, try now `File.foreach(file, :encoding => 'ascii-8:utf-8').first` ?

Comment: warning: Unsupported encoding ascii-8 ignored

Comment: I think I got it. `.encode('utf-8', 'binary', :invalid => :replace, :undef => :replace)`

Comment: It will do something else, not the one you are trying to do. :-)

Comment: Try this: File.foreach(file, :encoding => 'windows-1252:utf-8').first it's looking like it's encoded at latin1 supplemental

Comment: Read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12586731/2767755). There author explains well.

Comment: @rainkinz Yes, if the source file encoding is known, these types of issue can be handled easily.

Comment: Yeah, I'm just guessing it from his output above: "LOCATION,Feij\xF3,AC,a,b,c\r\n"` \xF3 is ó in latin supplemental

Comment: @rainkinz Perfect! Works!

Answer (score 3):

The character `ó` is `\xF3` in the [ISO-8859-1 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1), so this is probably the encoding of the file (it could also be [CP-1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cp1252).

You can specify the encoding as an arg to [`File::foreach`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/IO.html#method-c-foreach), and you can also ask Ruby to re-encode it to UTF-8 for you:

```
File.foreach(file, :encoding => 'iso-8859-1:utf-8').first.split(",")
```