# sidekiq active_job perform_later with text that includes UTF-8 characters

Tags: utf-8, sidekiq, rails-activejob

I just found this bug where I'm calling

```
MyJob.perform_later(request.body.read)
```

with a sidekiq active_job job,

the call `request.body.read` returns some json, I figured that in some cases it might contain chars that are UTF-8 (i.e. € symbol),

in this case I'm getting

```
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError Exception: "\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

I'm aware that sidekiq advises not to have complex or long job parameters, what would be a best practice workaround?

what I can think of is to base64 encode the string before passing it to the job (but this would make it even longer for sidekiq, I'm not sure this would be a problem)
or store the actual json text in a db table, and just pass to the job the id of the new row. this would definitely work, but looks like an overkill to me.

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sidekiq is going to use `JSON.generate` to serialize the job arguments.  This is an example of what is happening to your `ASCII-8BIT` string that you can run in the console:

```rb
arg = "Example with € character".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
JSON.generate([arg])
Encoding::UndefinedConversionError ("\xE2" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8)
```

One option would be to follow [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4875782/2622934) and force the encoding to UTF-8 before you pass it into `perform_later`.  Then it will serialize correctly:

```rb
arg = "Example with € character".force_encoding('ASCII-8BIT')
arg.force_encoding('UTF-8')
JSON.generate([arg])
 => "[\"Example with € character\"]"
```

So you'd want something like:

```
MyJob.perform_later(request.body.read.force_encoding('UTF-8'))
```